# New Icon on my Samsung S5 - what is it?

Tags: notification-icons

What is this notification bar icon on my Samsung S5?  It comes and go.  I do not recall seeing this a month ago.[image]

Answer (score 1):

"Big brother is watching you!"

Honestly: doing a Google reverse-image search came up with [this thread](https://androidforums.com/threads/eye-icon-meaning.1102549/), telling that feature is called

> Smart Stay. It shows up whenever it's checking if you're looking at the phone.
>
> Smart Stay is useful you know, that's what's preventing your screen from turning off at screen on time limit when you're using it.